# Doesnt output "Total" at the end of the table row with totals WITH ROLLUP?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my query, at the end of my table I have my totals of the three "SUMs" fields, but it doesnt output the text "TOTAL". Any suggestions?

```
$query = 'SELECT 
          IFNULL(fields_info.field_num,"TOTAL") AS `ff`,lands.city, farmers.first_name, farmers.last_name, seasons.season,
                                          SUM(fields_info.acreage) AS a, 
                                          SUM(fields_info.using_acreage) AS ua, 
                                          SUM(fields_info.unusing_acreage) AS una
          FROM fields

           LEFT JOIN regions ON id_region = regions.id
           LEFT JOIN lands ON regions.id_lands = lands.id                                    
           LEFT JOIN fields_info ON id_fields_info = fields_info.id
           LEFT JOIN farmers ON id_farmer = farmers.id
           LEFT JOIN seasons ON id_season = seasons.id
           WHERE CONCAT(farmers.first_name, " ", farmers.last_name) = \''.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fnzp']).'\'
                  AND seasons.season = \''.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['season']).'\'
           GROUP BY ff WITH ROLLUP';
```

This is my code for making the table:

```
$sql_select = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());   
$sql_select1 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());   

$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_select1);
echo "<table border='1' id='result_table'>
          <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <td class='tdata'>".$row1['first_name']. " " .$row1['last_name']."</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                  <th>Land</th>
                  <td class='tdata'>".$row1['city']."</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                  <th>Season</th>
                  <td class='tdata'>".$row1['season']."</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                  <td colspan='4'>&nbsp</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                  <th>Field num</th>
                  <th>Field acreage</th>
                  <th>Using acreage</th>
                  <th>Unusing acreageема площ</th>
          </tr>
              ";

if($query != "" && mysql_num_rows($sql_select) > 0 ) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_select))
    {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['ff'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['a'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['ua'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['una'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
}
else
  {
    echo '<tr><td colspan="5">No records in db.</td></tr>';
  }         
echo "</table>";
```

All in all everything is working fine except showing "TOTAL" at the last row where are my sums.

Comment: The only mentioning of any "TOTAL" is in the IFNULL. Probably the condition isn't in the favor of "TOTAL"?

Comment: You need to do the `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` in a subquery, and then check for `NULL` in the main query. In your version, the grouping is by the result of the `IFNULL`, so you can't test for the null that ROLLUP adds in there.